# BufferedImage & Rasters (Java)

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedimage, raster

Hi can someone explain this piece of code to me

```
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

From what I understand a raster simply represents a group of pixels. getDataBuffer() gives me the editable buffer, so that I can actually alter pixel properties. I am confused, primarily, about .getData() and the DataBufferInt cast, what exactly do those two things do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `image` is a `BufferedImage`, `getRaster()` will give you the `WritableRaster` for the image. Then, `getDataBuffer()` will give you the data buffer, which is a thin wrapper around the pixel array.

Because the native pixel arrays of a `BufferedImage` may be `byte[]`, `short[]`,  `int[]` or even `float[]` or `double[]`, multiple subclasses of `DataBuffer` exists for each type of backing array (there's even a `TYPE_USHORT` for unsigned `short` data, it's still using `short[]`). As there's no `getData()` or similar method in the abstract `DataBuffer` superclass, you need to cast the buffer to the proper subclass to be able to access the data in its native form. This is `DataBufferInt` in your case, but you can check it, using `dataBuffer.getType()`.

With the proper data buffer subclass, you can access the native pixels using the `getData()` method. You can now modify the pixels directly, any way you want.

However, note that accessing the pixel array directly will make your image "unmanaged", and disable some hardware accelerations of the `BufferedImage`. This may not be a problem, but it may cause slower rendering and frame rate drops, if you paint this image to screen often.